# Add onclient click to ASP.NET button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btncnclbkng" CssClass="divskyblue" runat="server" Text="CANCEL BOOKING" Enabled="false" Width="410px"  OnClientClick="return checkrecord();"/>
```

And javascript as below

```
function checkrecord() 
    {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure")) {
            return true
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

If i remove `Enabled="false"` from button then it asks confirmation but i adding and removing eneble-disable property  of button in javascript after making enable then its not working
.Please suggest me how to onclient click property to asp.net button in javascript

Comment: What does that mean: _"but i adding and removing eneble-disable property of button in java-script after making enable"_? Why would you ask for confirmation if the button is disabled?

Comment: create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: I guess you are mixing asp.net attributes and html attributes. See this to disable your button client side http://stackoverflow.com/a/13831737/1236044

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058116/confirm-postback-onclientclick-button-asp-net

Comment: initially my buttons is disabled..If it is not then javas-script given works fine for me on client click..I am making button enable  in javascript ..then after how can i add/register my java-script  to than button

Answer (score 1):

Use `disabled` attribute for your input. As this is a server attribute you can't enable/disable using JavaScript.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/5MjTJ/)</kbd>

Comment: @user2147551 - Does this answer your question?