# Delete Record From Asp.Net Formview Item Template

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to be able to delete a record from within an Asp.Net FormView ItemTemplate using an Asp button and an inline javascript confirm function.

The javascript works, I see the confirm dialog, when I click either button in the dialog, a postback does occur, but the record does not get deleted.

So far I have:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
     ID="btnDelete" 
     CssClass="NavigatorButton"    
     Text="Delete" 
     CausesValidation="true" 
     UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
     Visible="false" 
     CommandName="Delete" 
     OnClientClick="return confirm('This action will delete this provider note. Are you sure you wish to continue?');" />
```

The Delete works fine when I take the OnClientClick off the button, but I need the confirmation.

The javascript confirm works fine in the EditItem template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The confirm should only return a value if the user cancels out of the dialog else the page will not validate and postback.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058116/confirm-postback-onclientclick-button-asp-net) stack overflow post about it.

Comment: I read that post, it works fine for me in the EditItem Template, not in the Item Template.