# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>) error not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using some javascript code for validations which are as followed:-

```
var ErrArr = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            validateTitle();
            validateddl();
            validateTextBoxes();
            checkBoxChecking();
            if (ErrArr.length > 0) {
                alert(ErrArr.join("\n"));
                ErrArr = [];
                return false;
            }
        });
        function checkBoxChecking() {
            if ($("#chkDeclaration").is(":checked")) {
                // alert("first button checked");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                ErrArr.push('Check the declaration');
                return true;
            }
        }
        function validateTitle() {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                    ErrArr.push("Please enter the text in other title");
                }
            } else {
                ErrArr.push('Please select the title');
            }
        }
        function validateTextBoxes() {
            if ($("#txt_emp_fname").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('First name is required');
            }
            if ($("#txt_emp_mname").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Middle name is required');
            }
            if ($("#txt_emp_lname").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Last name is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtFatherName").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Father name is required');
            }

            if ($("#txtDateofJoin").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Date of joining is required');
            }

            if ($("#txtReligion").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Religion is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtPersonalEmail").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Email Id is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtDtOfBirth").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Date of birth is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtAt").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Place of birth is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtTaluka").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Taluka is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtPostOffice").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Post office is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtDistrict").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('District is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtStatePersonal").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('State is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtDtMarriage").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Date of Marriage is required');
            }
            if ($("#TxtPassportNo").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Passport no is required');
            }
            if ($("#txtIdMark").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Identification mark is required');
            }
        }
        function validateddl() {
            if ($("#ddlGender").val === "" || $("#ddlGender").val() == "0") {
                ErrArr.push('Please select the gender');
            }
            if ($("#ddlMaritalStatus").val === "" || $("#ddlMaritalStatus").val() == "0") {
                ErrArr.push('Please select the Marital Status');
            }
            if ($("#ddlNationality").val === "" || $("#ddlNationality").val() == "0") {
                ErrArr.push('Please select the Nationality');
            }
        }
    });
```

What happens here is, when I use this javascript code, my button click event does not fires. And when I remove the JS code, I get error as

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Here is my aspx code:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="button" Text="Save" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
                    OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Please note, I have searched and tried from other links available from stack and google but I couldn't succeed.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see this and use the `<asp:Button OnClickClick='..' />` property :

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028858/asp-net-button-onclientclick-return-function-vs-onclientclick-function) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058116/confirm-postback-onclientclick-button-asp-net) SO post for more.

```
<asp:Button 
 ID="btnSave" 
 CssClass="button" 
 Text="Save" 
 runat="server" 
 CausesValidation="true" 
 OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
 OnClientClick='return performValidation();'
/>
```

`performValidation` will be a master function to call that will **run first**, you can call your validation functions from within it. You should **return false if you don't want to page to be posted**.

Eg:

First modify each validation function to return false when the validation fails:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function checkBoxChecking() {
    if ($("#chkDeclaration").is(":checked")) {
       return false;
    }
    else {
       ErrArr.push('Check the declaration');
       return false; //return false when any validation fails.
    }
}
function validateTitle() {
    if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
        if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
            ErrArr.push("Please enter the text in other title");
        }
    } else {
        ErrArr.push('Please select the title');
        return false;//same here. return false when fail.
    }
}
 //this is your main validation function..
 function performValidation()
 {
    var ret = true;
    ret = checkBoxChecking();
    ret = validateTitle();
    //etc 
    //then ..
    return ret;
 }
});
```

Comment: at `performValidation()` which validations should I call ??

Comment: Put all the validation code inside there to check _"x field is required"_ ... (You could also call your already written validiation functions like `checkBoxChecking()` but they be should be modified to return a false if the validation fails and you should call them by doing `return checkBoxChecking();`

Comment: can you show me how to do it,as  I am confused a bit. Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/022tdvm3/ also how to call this function

Comment: What you linked should work. What exactly is happening. Do you see errors. etc? I've updated my answer with more code.

Comment: With my code, the page gets submitted without any validation messages. Let me try your updated code

Comment: how to debug js code ?? I have no idea how to debug it

Comment: Google for "developer tools" for the browser you're on, then you'll see a code window to put break points and debug.

Comment: OK, wel do that, And your updated code is also not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84566/discussion-between-nadeem-and-gideon).

Comment: @gideom: now validation is firing, but when I fill all the data, my `onClick` stops working. strange