# Call Javascript Confirm Box from Button event in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Hi I have been developing a page in asp.net web form. I have **cancel button**. When the cancel button is clicked I want to **generate a Confirm Message box**. Confirm Message box will appear based on some logic. If **Yes** is pressed from confirm box then button click will perform the **rest of the work.** And if **NO** is clicked then the rest of the work will not be done. I have written the following code both in server and client side. But it seems that confirm box is shown but if I click Yes the rest of the method function is not performed. Please let me know the problem.

**JavaScript Code**

```
function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel the creation of this new person?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            }
            else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
```

**Server Side Code**

```
if (IsFormDirty())
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "Confirm();", true);
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                if (!IsCprIxists())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hidGuid.LM_DataValue))
                    {
                        if (DeleteNote(hidGuid.LM_DataValue))
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("~/920.aspx?UseSessionState=Y");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/920.aspx?UseSessionState=Y");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/920.aspx?UseSessionState=Y");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you are using asp:Button here is [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058116/confirm-postback-onclientclick-button-asp-net)

Comment: sorry misunderstood question ))), you nee to submit form - document.forms[0].submit();